# Focused element with an attached blur or focusout event triggers it when clicked on a second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap's dropdown functionality with an input control to allow the user to either select  predefined values from a list or enter an arbitrary new one. Using jQuery I've attached a blur event so that when the user clicks outside the input it can do a minimal 'syntax' check to see if it is an allowed value. If so, an AJAX event is fired to updated that value in the user's profile.

If that input control is currently focused for typing in it (which has opened up the Bootstrap dropdown), if it is clicked upon a second time, such as clicking to move the text cursor around for editing the value being typed in, that attached blur event fires even though the input control it is firing on is retaining focus. The same thing happens with a focusout event instead of blur.

Is this the expected result with events, that the input control is actually losing and then immediately (re)gaining focus? The event.target value is the id of the element on which I attached the event, indicating this isn't bubbling from some other element, but could Bootstrap still have doesn't something funky and stolen focus when the dropdown appeared without somehow triggering the blur event then?

Regardless of how this is happening, can I stop it or work around it?

The HTML for the dropdown looks like this:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="input-group" id="l_album_drop" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <input class="form-control" id="l_default_album"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="caret dropdown-toggle" style="float:right;"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="height: auto; max-height: 256px; width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; border: silver solid 1px; padding: 2px;">
    <li class="default-album-selector-item" data-albumName="Everypost Photos" data-albumID="10154456500750072" data-albumLink="https://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=10154456500750072&id=10154515744420072&aid=1073741841" data-albumCoverPhoto="https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xtf1/t31.0-8/11807144_10155908179995072_3021817604288183977_o.jpg">Everypost Photos</li>
    <li class="default-album-selector-item" data-albumName="Piquero Photos" data-albumID="10155857109655072" data-albumLink="https://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=10155857109655072&id=10154515744420072&aid=1073741850" data-albumCoverPhoto="https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/11760176_10155857109690072_6083087322575761598_n.jpg?oh=c9861bd544f33bfd9b77fe9550943914&oe=5649D88D">Piquero Photos</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The javascript for the event looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#l_default_album").on(
  "blur",
  function(e) {
    if (typingLinked.newAlbumName) {
      clearTimeout(typingLinked.newAlbumName);
    }
    $("#l_default_album").closest(".dropdown-menu").prev().dropdown("toggle");
    checkDefaultAlbumCharacters();
  });
});
```

**Edit:**
I am using Chrome Version 44.0.2403.130 (64-bit) from the Google repo on Ubuntu 15.04 (64-bit).

Answer (score 1):

See this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/DTcHh/10905/

It is your HTML example with your JS replaced to only alert on `blur` event. (the example is using bootstrap v3)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#l_default_album").on(
  "blur",
  function(e) {
    alert('BLUR INVOKED');
  });
});
```

The `blur` event in invoked only when you leave the output field (click or by keypress ...).

Clicking inside i.e. positioning on your input is not invoking it. Cannot reproduce the behavior/bug you are describing in your question. The problem must be something else. Perhaps some other events of yours are interfering.

Comment: When I loaded your jsfiddle (thanks, BTW), I clicked on the field, typed "tseting", then clicked on the field again between the 't' and 's' as if to make an edit for bad typing and the event was triggered, popping up the alert box.

Comment: That should not (and it doesn't) invoke blur event. I tried the same thing. I am using Chrome Version 44.0.2403.130 m. I can click as many as I want inside my input field, the blur event won't be fired until I click outside or press tab.

Comment: With deadlines and all, I just got rid of the blur event. Today had time to go and disable all the plugins, just in case there was some weirdness with stealing mouse cursor focus but not keyboard caret focus by the extra divs plugins like Rbutr, LastPass and others add. Unfortunately the same thing happend. Click on the field, type with an intentional mistake, click back between the letters to reposition the keyboard caret and the on blur event gets triggered and the alert box is displayed. There has to be some explanation why it would be happening for me and not for you.